# 6242 people view a question and I am the first to upvote an answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am not sure if this is a glitch or just a really weird coincidence. I was looking at the question [Can a Windows XP desktop be made into a WiFi hotspot?](https://superuser.com/questions/410811/can-a-windows-xp-desktop-be-made-into-a-wifi-hotspot) and out of the 6242 people who have viewed this question I was the very first person to up-vote or down-vote any answer seance April of last year.

Is this a glitch of the vote counting or just out of the 6k people no one really cared?

Comment: given that we don't have access to vote data, guess no one really cared. The timeline says the same http://superuser.com/posts/410811/timeline

Comment: 10 months, 6k views, A couple good answers IMHO (that's why I up-voted) and no votes? I am just having a really having a hard time believing it.

Comment: Wait, what?  Who was having a séance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider that it's talking about Windows XP, something regulars to the site likely no longer use unless forced, and you have mostly one-time visitors from search engines.

There's quite a bit of anonymous feedback for the question and its answers though, which is recorded similar to votes, but doesn't affect a post's score (and isn't visible on the site): Based on data from February 3rd, [all answers to the question only received negative feedback](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/95383/anonymous-feedback-for-a-certain-question-and-its-answers?PostId=410811).

So recording works just fine, it's just that the answers aren't popular or considered helpful: People generally don't like answers telling them something isn't possible the way they'd like.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for helping me see it that way.

Comment: excellent stuff in pulling up the data